# Async client-server pattern

Tags: design-patterns, server, client

I want to make a local service. User will upload some files, that would be parsed by server. At the end of the process the user should get the result. The process is completely asynchronous, so the user may not get the result immediately.

Sound familiar?

I don't want to reinvent the bicycle, so I need advice on what pattern exists for this kind of client/server interaction?
Maybe there is a good book on this topic, it's even better!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user does the upload and gets a jobid. Based on the jobid, they can then ask the server whether the job is done yet by for example refreshing the page. When the job is done, they can then there see the result of the job.

Instead of refreshing the page, you can also keep the connection open and push updates to the client, but that's just a bit of an extension.